# Get absolute path of relative path stored in variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Within a script I have a variable which contains a relative path to a directory.  Is there any way to get the absolute path of the contents of this variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
# cd /var/lib/foo
# rpath=../../bar
# echo $(cd "$rpath" && pwd)
/bar
# pwd
/var/lib/foo
```

Comment: This works when the name is a directory; it doesn't when the name is a file (and a close reading of the question suggests file rather than directory).